# What does "before it" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"We don’t usually worry about not existing for all those millennia before our birth. Why should anyone care about all that time that they didn’t exist? But then, if that’s true, why should we care so much about all those aeons of non-existence after death? Our thought is asymmetrical.We’re very biased towards worrying about the time after our death rather than the time before our birth. But Epicurus thought this was a mistake. Once you see this, you should start thinking of the time after your death in the same sort of way that you do the time **before it**".
[A Little History of Philosophy - by Nigel Warburton, p.26]

What did the author mean when he wrote "before it"? "before it" = "before your death" or "before it" = "before your birth"? Please explain this to me! Thank you

Comment: Look at just the sentence where it is used: "Once you see this, you should start thinking of the time after your death in the same sort of way that you do the time before it." Can you answer your own question now?

Comment: I think you're quite right that the writer has got his concepts a bit confused. I'm sure he's not saying you should think of *(**your**)* time before death the same as the period before it (during which you're ***alive***). Obviously he's contrasting the time before you were born with the time after you're dead, so he should have written *before **your birth***, not ***it***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. Here "it" creates the ambiguity that is confusing OP. But really, because of the theme of the paragraph, what it does say and what it should say are probably two different things

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the ambiguity arises from sloppy writing in the last sentence of the quoted paragraph.  There is no interesting English question here.

Comment: "....before it" should be ".....before your birth."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because covered in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree that the writer was sloppy. The ambiguity here is that 'it' clearly refers to the time before death when what the writer most likely meant to say is that we don't worry about the time before birth.